# Acer e1-572 wont boot and cant access BIOS

Tags: boot, bios, acer-aspire

My laptop wont boot, it is stuck in Acer logo splash screen

F2 and F12 buttons dont do anything 
Reseating ram and hard drive did not solve
Holding power for 2s or 2min does not work
Only power light and batterys light stays on
It started after I changed from Legacy to UEFI with Secure Boot disabled
 disconnected everything( battery and adapter) and held the power button for 10s.

Then I tried powering the PC with only Adapter or battery or both, and the results were the same: The almost instant acer logo screen

But I discovered that my HDD is making a very quiet sound, which I guess is a good thing

It is a laptop E1-572-6_BR648

Comment: Try other buttons. ESC, F10, F9, etc. loop through them, tapping them all during the power on sequence. Also, you can pull the hard drive out temporarily and power on. This should get you to an error screen or something that will let you back in the BIOS. You can't change from legacy to UEFI, or vice/versus without significant changes to the OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My pc started to give only power light. No buttons do anything. I think the Motherboard got murdered by my continuous hard restart. Gonna go to a repair shop and fix it. tanhks for answering.